# 'Database' of Articles and Videos, without access to server side scripting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

I am in a pickle.

I could easily solve this problem with PHP or a CMS, but I don't have access to these because of the restrictions of the client's server. So, I need to make due without it.

I have a collection of articles, with related videos and pictures, that need to be displayed on multiple pages. So, let's say 'John' wrote an article about Dalmations. His article needs to show up on the 'John' page, as well as the 'Dogs' page, and also on an 'All Articles' page.

How should I go about doing this?

I could copy and paste the html, but then if I wanted to make a change, I would have to change it on several different pages.

So, my current—and lame—solution to throw the article in an html document, and then put iframes on the 'John' and 'Dog' page. This has a host of problems including the inability to resize iframes based on the contained content. There has to be a better way.

I've searched as best as I could, but haven't come up with anything. Would it be better to use XML and iframes? jQuery / AJAX? I really just don't know what the best option is.

Thank you.

Comment: What **is** available on the server? I mean there are always old school Server Side Includes (.shtml).

Comment: ***No*** server-side scripting? Dude, find a new client.

Comment: What do you think of this: [inc](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/inc-a-super-tiny-client-side-include-javascript-jquery-plugin.html)?

Comment: Bummer, could you do something with XSLT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make some simple build tooling. For example in the past ive used `rake`, `phing`, `ant`, or something custom on some projects that needed to run as static html. This allows me to keep thing separate like you would on a dynamic project and then compile them down to static html files.

Id recommend doing this over using client side calls.

Comment: Do you know of any similar, but GUI tools?

Comment: Well if you use Eclipse as an IDE i think you can create and configure `ant` build tasks in the GUI. Other than that the only thing i know of off hand would be Dreamweaver. It supports Templates and Library items (what one would call "view partials" in a typical dynamic application context) and then updates (eg. builds) everything when you modify them.

Comment: Oh you can probably get the same `ant` integration from NetBeans as well.